# Is it possible to do A/B testing with Adsense ad positions?

Tags: google-adsense, a-b-testing

I was just looking at Google Website Optimizer, however you need a 'conversion' page in order to measure results. If trying to optimize ad positions, this doesn't appear to be possible.

Even without GWO I can't see a way to track clicks in Adsense, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to set up multiple channels for each site, and then use those channels for your split testing.

Earnings on a particular page in analytics could be somehow done if you add a parameter to one version of the page depending on your frameowrk and how you are modifying the pages themselves for the test.
I am not quite sure how the different channels would work in analyics...

It might be a little easier using Reedge.com as you might find it easier doing the split testing.

Comment: Yes, channels sounds like a very usable idea. I can set up the varying pages myself, then let Adsense handle all the data collection.